# How to insert/inject a fake user (IPrincipal)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, windows-authentication

We are required to use Windows authentication on a new project. So we will be  utilizing the AuthorizeAttribute on action methods, and perhaps also within a limited number of controller actions.

Works great, of course. But to test this (both in unit testing, and in testing by hand as I integrate this stuff), I need to be able to simulate a user with any role, and to switch frequently back and forth between different roles.

I cannot modify the controller's User object (it's readonly), so **from where can I insert a fake user that implements IPrincipal** that to be accessed everywhere in my app, including:

- in controller-actions
- in custom attributes

I have not yet dived into DI frameworks -- will one be necessary at this point? If you strongly recommend so, I'd still like to know how to do this via "poor-man's" DI.

Comment: Have you looked at the [MvcContrib Test Helper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `global.asax` / `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)`.

That method is invoked after ASP.NET have had it's fun with the principal.

If you only want to provide your own roles you could just implement a `RoleProvider` instead.

**Update**

You can do this:

```
public void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var principal = LoadFromTheDb();
    HttpContext.Current.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
}
```

And then you can use that principal wherever you like.

If you have enabled `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` in web.config you should probably check if the user is authenticated first before doing anything else.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Would I be able to set the User property of HttpContext from here (I don't see how)?  Also: Is this event valid for MVC, or just Web Forms?

Comment: not sure why, but Application_OnPostAuthenticate() isn't working. However I can set the user in Application_Start(), which is also in global.asax, of course, and will suffice.

Comment: That wont work, the user will always be the same no matter who logs in.

Comment: Opps. the name should be `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`. Set a break point in it to verify.

Comment: thanks -- that works now. Better than application_start(), of course.